# Open page in Parent, Tab or Pop-Up

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, actions

I'm working on an application with a lot of user functionality and navigation which stems from the ability to create, edit,update,delete (C.R.U.D) the majority of objects/entities.

My question is, when navigating with C.R.U.D. functionality, what are the recommendations or standards with displaying content.

Would you for example, when editing a user's profile (customer info): 
 a) Have a pop-up window where you can edit fields
 b) Replace / refresh whole page with an editable page.
 c) Open a new tab for to work in when editing this content.

Comment: Is this accessible on mobile?

Comment: There will be a mobile application, whether we use the existing application or build a full mobile application is to be determined.

Comment: In general, there are usually few good arguments for creating new browser windows/tabs. However, in-page modals can certainly be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its going to hard to recommend a solution unless we see some wireframe  of what the current design looks like.

However I would recommend doing an inline edit which allows users to quickly change the value and then publish the updates. Facebook does this pretty well as shown below

[image]

This design scales well when users can edit a lot of different items which are independent of each other as the user can focus on just the one item they wish to edit and not be required to enter the other details again as shown below

[image]

The challenge with a popup is scalablity as the size of the forms to edit might be too huge to display. If you are going for small edits as shown above, it would be annoying for the user to have a popup for every edit and it would also hide the content below which might be needed for him to update his information

Putting it on another tab will not work as the user will need to keep on switching between both tabs to compare if the need arises

Comment: I was considering using inline editing, but I was wondering if it would become redundant for our users. This will be an enterprise application, and users will have a repetitive workflow,I was thinking that having to deal with editing individual sections could become frustrating task.  Do you have any thoughts on this? This was the issue that pushed me to doing a full edit page instead of inline editing.

Comment: What would be more frustrating for users,just doing a quickly inline edit or having to edit a whole form again